# Blazor - passing arguments to parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

How to pass multiple arguments from child to parent upon onClick event in child component

Child Razor

```
@foreach( var item in items)
{
  @foreach( var score in item.scores)
  {
    <span @onclick="ItemClicked(item.name, score.id)"> 
      @item.name 
    </span>
  }
}
```

Parent Razor

```
<Child ItemClicked = "@ItemClicked"/>

@code{
 private void ItemClicked(string name, int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: ItemClicked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Child

```
<span @onclick = "() => ItemClicked(item.name, score.id)"> @item.name</span>

@code 
{
   [Parameter] public Action<string,int> ItemClicked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How to handle it in the parent component ?

Comment: You are already doing that. WriteLine() will work fine. If you want to update the UI you will need StateHasChanged().

Comment: Parameter is not valid on this declaration ? its only valid on property

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087832/blazor-compare-previous-and-next-state

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create a new class for the arguments you're trying to pass back up to the parent. In this example, I'm using a generic checkbox component that I pass an Id and a Checked property because I need to know what item I'm selecting in the parent component as well as if it's checked or not. So the event needs to know the Id and whether it's checked. The child component contains it's own logic and then passes up a new object with the assigned values which the parent can now use.

Parent

```
<Checkbox Id="@Id" Checked="@Item.Checked" CheckChanged="OnCheck" />
```

```cs
public class OnCheckEventArgs
{
    public bool IsChecked {get; set;}
    public long ItemId {get; set;}
}

public class ItemsOverview : ComponentBase
{
    public void OnCheck(OnCheckEventArgs args)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Child

```
<input type="checkbox" Id="@Id" checked="@Checked" @onchange="CheckboxChanged" />
```

```cs
public partial class Checkbox : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public long Id {get; set;}

    [Parameter]
    public bool Checked {get; set;}

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<OnCheckEventArgs> CheckChanged {get; set;}

    protected async Task OnCheckChange(bool checked)
    {
        // do stuff
        await CheckChanged.InvokeAsync(new OnCheckEventArgs { IsChecked = checked, ItemId = @Id });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You Need to assign it to a eventcallback wich only receive one parameter, so you can create a dictionary or make a class and pass it in the object.

You pass the whole item to the Parent component, then you can get the id from here.

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    @foreach (var score in item.scores)
    {
        <span @onclick="OnItemClick.InvokeAsync(item)">
            @item.name
        </span>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<_TYPE_OF_YOUR_ITEM> OnItemClick { get; set; }
}
```

```
<Child OnItemClick="HandleItemClick">

@code {
   private void HandleItemClick(_TYPE_OF_YOUR_ITEM) 
   {
      // Handle your event here
   }
}
```

With a dictionary

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
    @foreach (var score in item.scores)
    {
        <span @onclick="HandleClick(item, score.id)">
            @item.name
        </span>
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> OnItemClick { get; set; }

    private void HandleClick(dynamic item, int score)
    {
        var parameter = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        parameter.Add("Item", item);
        parameter.Add("ScoreId", score);

        OnItemClick.InvokeAsync(parameter);
}
}
```

```
   private void HandleItemClick(dictionary<string, dynamic> parameters) 
   {
      // extract your parameters and handle
      // parameters["ScoreId"], parameters["item"]

   }
```

Comment: sorry, can u elaborate ? I am new to C#, my background is Javascript. I have edited the question.

Comment: I think the others have betters responses.

Comment: if u notice onclick I want to pass not the item only, I want to pass the item.name and score.id.

Comment: Oh yes, so you can make a dictionary an pass a type of dictionary like so

Comment: I added an example using dictionary

Comment: You can pass yout whole score too.

Comment: Your first attempt was close - just `() => OnItemClick?.InvokeAsync(item)`. The parameter(s) are a matter of choice.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but found the answer Henk more easier, take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, EventCallback is preferred in direct binding. It's type-safe and calls StateHasChanged() automatically. I don't think it matters a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that "ItemClicked" is EventCallback parameter.
If so, you can create an object like

```
Class Student
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use like

*Parent*

```
 private void ItemClicked(Student student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(student.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(student.Id);
    }
```

*Child*

```
<span @onclick = "ItemClicked(student)"> @item.name </span>
```

Comment: My intention was to pass the name and the Id from inside the foreach loop, but in ur answer u r passing student, I am not sure from where u r getting that ?

Comment: I have edited the Question for better understanding. thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft documentation, maybe you want to do binding instead?
Here's the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

search for "Child-to-parent binding with chained bind"

```
<h1>Child Component</h1>
<input @oninput="OnPasswordChanged" 
   required 
   type="@(showPassword ? "text" : "password")" 
   value="@Password" />
@code {
    private bool showPassword;

    [Parameter]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> PasswordChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnPasswordChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Password = e.Value.ToString();

        return PasswordChanged.InvokeAsync(Password);
    }


}
```

parent:

```
<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<PasswordField @bind-Password="password" />

@code {
    private string password;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I do need the function ItemClicked in the parent to perform some actions when span from the child is clicked, I do understand ur answer but how can u console log the password when ever it changes in the parent component?

Comment: Sorry not exactly understanding your comment question. If the value in parents changed, you just need to do stateHasChanged and it should be recomputed. I did find there are times it the system didn't compute, I just had to force it by changing some top level variables. I think there's documentation somewhere to do that...  I can't remember right now.

Comment: I think you can also write an event handler in the parent, so when child is clicked, you call the event handler in the parent. For example, parents has to pass an EventCallback Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer: since you changed your ask

maybe event handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Read this section: EventCallback and think about EventCallback

child:
    
        Trigger a Parent component method

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClickCallback { get; set; }
```

parent:

```
<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent"
            OnClickCallback="@ShowMessage">
    Content of the child component is supplied
    by the parent component.
</ChildComponent>

@code{

    private void ShowMessage(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        messageText = $"Blaze a new trail with Blazor! ({e.ScreenX}, {e.ScreenY})";
    }

}
```

you might need @on{EVENT}:preventDefault